# Solve "The command "taskkill /F /IM MyApp.vshost.exe" exited with code 128" error

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, command-line, build

**Context**
When debugging (with the *Debug* menu <kbd>F5</kbd>) a Visual Studio solution, a process called `MyApp.vshost.exe` is created. When you stop the debug *indecently* - I mean using the *Stop Debug* menu <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> and not waiting for a code line like `Application.Exit()` occurs - this process is not killed.

Sometimes, when you later start again debugging your application, an error message occurs, saying that the file (obviously, it is the file used by the debug: `bin\Debug\MyApp.vshost.exe`) is already in use.

That is why I added to the Build events this command line: `taskkill /F /IM MyApp.vshost.exe`

**Problem**
When the `MyApp.vshost.exe`process does not exist, Visual Studio is sometimes throwing an error at build time, thus preventing to build the application:

```
Error c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets
The command "taskkill /F /IM MyApp.vshost.exe" exited with code 128.
```

The only existing solution i found is to remove the build event.

**Question**
Is there a way to resolve the error message without removing the build event?

## EDIT

I'm thinking the best solution would be to retrieve the return code (`errorlevel`) of the command, then return 0 if it is equal to 128. Is it possible to do it in the Build events of the project?

Comment: Can you expand on what you're application is doing? For example, are you interfacing with out of process apps such as Excel or Word via the Office Interop bits?

Comment: @Kev: I have the problem with all my applications - _Windows form projects_ and _Windows services_ and some are not working with Excel nor Word. The simplest app I have is a service that got a timer checking in a MSSQL database and execute simple tasks.

Comment: any solution, similar problem using msbuild: MSBUILD : warning MSB3073: The command "DEL "C:\Clientes\*.*" /q /f /s" exited with code 128.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
taskkill /F /IM MyApp.vshost.exe 2>&1 || exit /B 0
```

Comment: This worked for me, except I had problems until I removed the double pipes, and made it a single pipe `||` to `|`

Comment: I would suggest to use conditional testing: `taskkill /f /fi "pid gt 0" /im MyApp.vshost.exe` [Source](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15748825/426315)

Comment: Same here. In VS 2015, single pipe works 

taskkill /f /im excel.exe  2>&1 | exit /B 0

Comment: In theory it should be double pipe: "The double pipe (||) causes the command following this symbol to run if the command preceding the symbol fails". From http://windowsitpro.com/windows/jsi-tip-0290-conditional-processing-symbols-filters-and-redirection-batch-processing

Answer (score 2):

As a temporary measure you can disable the Visual Studio host process:

> [How to: Disable the Hosting Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms185330.aspx)
>
> **To disable the hosting process**
>
> Open a project in Visual Studio.
>
> On the Project menu, click Properties.
>
> Click the Debug tab.
>
> Clear the Enable the Visual Studio hosting process check box.

The side effects of doing this may or may not be desirable:

> In general, when the hosting process is disabled:
>
> The time needed to begin debugging .NET Framework applications
>   increases.
>
> Design-time expression evaluation is unavailable.
>
> Partial trust debugging is unavailable.

Answer (score 2):

The `MyApp.vshost.exe` is the [Visual Studio hosting process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms242202.aspx). The purpose of this process is to improve the debugging experience. If you kill this process yourself Visual Studio will recreate it. If you want to get rid of it you can turn off the hosting process in the debugging properties for the project (C# shown here):

[image: Debug project properties]

You describe the error you experience as "the process is already in use". I don't think I have experienced that myself but on a work PC I'm having great troubles when building after debugging. It seems that `MyApp.exe` is locked and cannot be overwritten ("file is already in use", not "process") causing the build to fail. By belief is that a virus scanner (Microsoft Forefront) are causing these problems, but being in a corporate environment I can't turn off the scanner to test my hypothesis.

In many cases disabling the hosting process will not have a noticable effect on your debugging experience.

Comment: That is right, it is _"file already in use"_ and not _"process"_. I edited my Q.

Answer (score -1):

running perhaps as administrator with full privileges the IDE ? ( I know this was suggested once upon a time from Microsoft )

Comment: Nah, not running the IDE as administrator.