# defining custom batch file error code in VS2012 IDE

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch file that is executed as part of pre-build events in VC++ based project , within VS2012 IDE framework.The file , on error does following:

```
exit /B 0
:Error0
echo ****************************************************************************
set ErrorMssg="Attributes don't match"    
echo ****************************************************************************
exit /B 1
```

When executed from shell(wIn 7),it prints the error message correctly, when error condition is hit.
However, from within Visual Studio, I only get error code, which i specified in the batch file:

> error MSB3073: :VCEnd" exited with code 1

Is there a way for Visual Studio to actually print the reason for error,for example something like

> error MSB3073: :VCEnd" exited with code 1: Attributes don't match

Thanks
sedy

Answer (score 0):

With the call to your pre-build batch file try redirecting `stderr` to `stdout` with `2>&1`, see;

- [How to modify return code in Visual Studio Build events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7912726/how-to-modify-return-code-in-visual-studio-build-events)
- [Swallowing errors in pre-build steps in Visual Studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5806444/swallowing-errors-in-pre-build-steps-in-visual-studio-2010)

Comment: Moreover, I can echo the error before exiting, but that shows on a different line than the line quoted above and i was hoping to append my error message  to  VS standard error message.

Comment: @user915783 yes https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/110930 but not exactly sure how that plays with the VS output window though