# Visual Studio pre-build event check to see if a directory (and file) exists and delete it if it does

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2015, prebuild

Every time I do a build I would like for this Pre-build event to occur:

```
del  $(ProjectDir)\obj\Debug\Package\PackageTmp\web.config
```

This works fine if the directory is there.  But if the directory is not there then it will cause the build to fail.  I tried doing something like this to check if the directory was there:

```
if Exists('$(ProjectDir)\obj\Debug\Package\PackageTmp\')   
del  $(ProjectDir)\obj\Debug\Package\PackageTmp\web.config
```

But I believe my syntax is wrong because I get a exit code of 255.  What would be the proper way to get this to work?

Thanks!

Comment: It is not a function that takes parentheses, its name is exist.  Use double-quotes.  if exist "path" del "path"

Comment: Are you talking inside the actual xml file itself?  Or the editor window in the Properties page in VS?  I have tried this over a dozen ways and am having no luck in getting this to work.

Comment: Another way: ignore the exit code, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7912726/how-to-modify-return-code-in-visual-studio-build-events/7913356#7913356

Answer (score 16):

Apparently this works:

```
if EXIST "$(ProjectDir)\obj\Debug\Package\PackageTmp\web.config" (
del  "$(ProjectDir)\obj\Debug\Package\PackageTmp\web.config"
)
```

The above piece of code was one of the first ways I tried doing this.  But it kept failing.  After many more attempts I ended up restarting Visual Studio 2015 and entering that code again and then it started working.

Answer (score 4):

I would use a target to accomplish this. Specifically, I would suggest overriding a `BeforeBuild` target. There are a couple different ways to do this, but the simplest is to modify your `.vcxproj` file IMHO.

At the bottom of your project file (you can edit it by right-clicking on your project in Visual Studio -> Unload Project, then right-click again and choose to edit that project) you should see an `<Import ...` line. Add a target after that line that's something like this:

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild" Condition="Exists('$(ProjectDir)\obj\Debug\Package\PackageTmp\web.config')">
  <Delete Files="$(ProjectDir)\obj\Debug\Package\PackageTmp\web.config" />
</Target>
```

See [How to: Extend the Visual Studio Build Process](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366724.aspx) for more information on overriding Before and After targets.